# What is the best way to show the data in hierarchical display in SQL (HIERARCHYID is not working properly)?

Tags: sql-server-2008, hierarchyid

What is the best possible way to show the data in hierarchical display, i have used HIERARCHYID in sql but i am not able to get the data properly when it's level exceeds to more than 10 (horizontal and vertical) level.

Please share your experience on it.